# Check for value is N/A

Tags: php, if-statement, isnull

I am integrating an API and in some cases bonus field return value N/A and I want not to show N/A on the page.If the field has any text other than N/A then it shows the text.

I tried this:

```
    if(trim($value) != "N/A" && !is_null($value))
    {
        echo $value;
    }
```

But the above condition is not working.

Can anyone help me to make it working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use OR (||) instead of AND &&

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: will you show possible values for `$value`?

Comment: I used var_dumb() to check the type of data returned from the API, The type is string when it return N/A the var dump show string(20). 20 is the length of string but it should be 3. may be it includes white space. That's why i used trim. API will return numeric values and string values. Numeric values in case there is discount and string value to show message and N/A.

Answer (score 0):

One answer from the oneliners club:

```
empty($value) or $value == 'N/A' or print($value);
```

"print" will only be reached if the $value is not set and is not "N/A"